# How do I disable default text selection behavior in a WKWebView

Tags: swift

I have an app that loads a WkWebView, in that WebView there is JavaScript that is triggered when a text range is selected within the content. That script displays a HTML control on the page.

The problem occurs when the IOS menu (copy/define/share) shows up.

**Problem 1**

When the text is selected (long press) the HTML control is displayed.
When you lift your finger from the screen, the IOS copy/define thing shows up, and the HTML control disappears. Adjusting the text range with the UI controls brings the HTML control back.

**Desired behavior:**

The IOS "menu" whatever it is actually called, is not necessary and I dont want it to be displayed. I also do not want the HTML control to go away, but I don't know what IOS is doing to make it happen. On the HTML page itself, clicking anywhere but the action button removes the selection and the HTML control. How do I disable this behavior?

**Problem 2**

Attempting to adjust the text selection range with the ui control at the end of the selection sometimes results in everything prior to the endpoint ui control to be selected.

**Desire behavior:**

For it not to do this. How to I prevent it from moving the side of the selection control that I am not touching?

Answer (score 2):

I have a same problem and here is my solution:
Selection menu shows in UICalloutBar. I find UICalloutBar view and remove it before it showed.

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(menuWillShow:) name:UIMenuControllerWillShowMenuNotification object:[UIMenuController sharedMenuController]];
}
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIMenuControllerWillShowMenuNotification object:[UIMenuController sharedMenuController]];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
-(void)findUI:(UIView*) view{
    if([@"UICalloutBar" isEqualToString:[[view class] description]]){
        //NSLog(@"UIView:%@",[[view class] description]);
        [view removeFromSuperview ];
    //[view setAlpha:0];
        return;
    }

    for(UIView* subview in view.subviews){
        [self findUI: subview];
    }
}
-(void)menuWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSArray* windows = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows];
    for(UIWindow* window in windows){
        if([@"UITextEffectsWindow" isEqualToString:[[window class] description]]){
            [self findUI:window];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After many hours searching solution for that, I decide using View UI Hierarchy in Xcode to find where is selection menu ui component. I found "UICalloutBar" ui and there is code to find and remove it. And it works.

Comment: I thing apple doesn't allow app to AppStore if app uses such private classes..so I'm really curious about your app?

Comment: Also, this solution won't work now since hierarchy for `UITextEffectsWindow` got changed, `UITextEffectsWindow` is not subview of 'UIWindow'